# Why does the method of inserting a node by index not work?

Tags: javascript

I want to insert a node by index using the `add ()` method  but it does not work help fix it.

**This is how the call should look like:**

```
list.add ('2', 1); // At the list: '1', '2', '3'
```

**But when I make a call an error is triggered:**

```
throw new Error("Position Node Doesnt Exist!")
```

**All my code:**

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value; // value in the node
        this.next = null; // link to the next node
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        /*pointer to the knot-head
         (first element) of the list*/
        this.head = null;
        /*pointer to the node-tail
         (last item) of the list*/
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

//insert to the beginning (returns the inserted value)
    addFirst(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.head) {
            newNode.next = this.head;
            //this.head = newNode;
        } else {//Linked list is empty
            this.tail = newNode;
            //this.head = newNode
        }
        //set the head to the new node
        this.head = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }

//insert to the end(returns the inserted value)
    addLast(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.tail) {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode;
        } else {
            this.head = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode
        }
        this.tail = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }

    findIndex(item) {
        let currentNode = this.head;
        while (currentNode) {
            if (currentNode.value === item) {
                return currentNode;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    add(value, index) {
        //create the new node based on the name passed
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //find the position or item node we want to insert after.
        let positionNode = this.findIndex(index);
        if (positionNode != null) {
            //first set the next pointer of new node to be that of position nodes next
            newNode.next = positionNode.next;
            //finally update the positionNode's next to be the new node
            positionNode.next = newNode;
            this.length++;

        } else {
            //position not found, return error
            throw new Error("Position Node Doesnt Exist!")
        }
    }
}
let list = new SinglyLinkedList();
list.addFirst('1');
list.addLast('3');
list.add('2', 1);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: if i do this i see error: "Uncaught Error: Position Node Doesnt Exist!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare strings with numbers in the `findIndex` method at:

```
if (currentNode.value === item) {
```

To allow auto type coercion, you can use the double equal operator. Or you could convert both values to the same type(number or string)

```
if (currentNode.value == item) {
```

Please find the edited working snippet below.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value; // value in the node
        this.next = null; // link to the next node
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        /*pointer to the knot-head
         (first element) of the list*/
        this.head = null;
        /*pointer to the node-tail
         (last item) of the list*/
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

//insert to the beginning (returns the inserted value)
    addFirst(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.head) {
            newNode.next = this.head;
            //this.head = newNode;
        } else {//Linked list is empty
            this.tail = newNode;
            //this.head = newNode
        }
        //set the head to the new node
        this.head = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }

//insert to the end(returns the inserted value)
    addLast(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.tail) {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode;
        } else {
            this.head = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode
        }
        this.tail = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }

    findIndex(item) {
        let currentNode = this.head;
        while (currentNode) {
            if (currentNode.value == item) {
                return currentNode;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    add(value, index) {
        //create the new node based on the name passed
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //find the position or item node we want to insert after.
        debugger;
        let positionNode = this.findIndex(index);
        if (positionNode != null) {
            //first set the next pointer of new node to be that of position nodes next
            newNode.next = positionNode.next;
            //finally update the positionNode's next to be the new node
            positionNode.next = newNode;
            this.length++;

        } else {
            //position not found, return error
            throw new Error("Position Node Doesnt Exist!")
        }
    }
}
let list = new SinglyLinkedList();
list.addFirst('1');
list.addLast('3');
list.add('2', 1);
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could track which index you're on within `findIndex` instead of comparing values.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value; // value in the node
        this.next = null; // link to the next node
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        /*pointer to the knot-head
         (first element) of the list*/
        this.head = null;
        /*pointer to the node-tail
         (last item) of the list*/
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

//insert to the beginning (returns the inserted value)
    addFirst(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.head) {
            newNode.next = this.head;
            //this.head = newNode;
        } else {//Linked list is empty
            this.tail = newNode;
            //this.head = newNode
        }
        //set the head to the new node
        this.head = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }

//insert to the end(returns the inserted value)
    addLast(value) {
        //create a new Node
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //Handle case for when linked list is not empty
        if (this.tail) {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode;
        } else {
            this.head = newNode;
            //this.tail = newNode
        }
        this.tail = newNode;
        //increment count
        this.length++;
    }

    findIndex(item) {
        let currentNode = this.head;
        let index = 0;
        while (currentNode) {
            if (index === item - 1) {
                return currentNode;
            }
            index++;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    add(value, index) {
        //create the new node based on the name passed
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        //find the position or item node we want to insert after.
        let positionNode = this.findIndex(index);
        if (positionNode != null) {
            //first set the next pointer of new node to be that of position nodes next
            newNode.next = positionNode.next;
            //finally update the positionNode's next to be the new node
            positionNode.next = newNode;
            this.length++;

        } else {
            //position not found, return error
            throw new Error("Position Node Doesnt Exist!")
        }
    }
}
let list = new SinglyLinkedList();
list.addFirst('1');
list.addLast('3');
list.add('2', 1);
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logics seems wrong.
The findindex function  finds the item with the some value.
You call it with an index as a parameter... That is wrong.
You need a findItem method with index as parameter

```
    if(index<0||index>length) {return null or head or tail...} 
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let currentIndex=0;
    while (currentIndex<index) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        CurrentIndex++;
    }
    return currentNode;
```